# Running Poetry install command gives error : list index out of range

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python project, for that, I need to install the dependencies I am using poetry when running the install command I get this error

```
[IndexError]  
list index out of range
```

Python version 3.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a simpler method for this:

install pyenv https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer

with pyenv run command.

```
pyenv install 3.6.8
```

this will install python 3.6.8 for pyenv

create a virtual environment

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.6.8 my-3.6.8
pyenv activate my-3.6.8
```

After this you can run your Poetry install command